# Is using a CDN for bootstrap faster than loading it as files on the site?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I want to make a social network website.
I want compatibility and good css, not incompatible css.
I want to conform to W3C standards.

So, is loading Bootstrap from a CDN for every page faster than using files already in the server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a CDN will in most cases be faster. They are a network of geographically dispersed servers. Being able to serve your content closer to somebody can make a lot of difference to load times.

There's a lot of resources that can be found online which outline the benefits of using a CDN (Content Delivery Network). Here's a few that explain what they are, and why you should use them if available.

- http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/
- https://gtmetrix.com/why-use-a-cdn.html